# Issue at the time of convert JSON object

Tags: angularjs, json

Need to convert below string into object

```
"{"taskStatus":"Not Started","taskFields":{"originalTransactionDate":"${datafield:feerefund:originalTranDate}","transactionPostingDate":"${datafield:feerefund:tranPostingDate}","referenceNumber":"${datafield:feerefund:referenceNum}","promotionIdentifier":"${datafield:feerefund:promoId}","merchantAdjustmentDescription":"${datafield:feerefund:merchantAdjDesc}","transactionAmount":"${datafield:feerefund:tranAmount}","batchPrefix":"${datafield:feerefund:batchPrefix}","transactionCode":"${datafield:feerefund:tranCode}"}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at JSON.parse:

```
let object = JSON.parse(string)
```

where string is your json string

Comment: I have updated my string but you provided solution not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Correct JSON String is

```
"{"taskStatus":"Failed","taskFields":{"originalTransactionDate":"2017-08-17","transactionPostingDate":"2017-08-17","referenceNumber":"12345","promotionIdentifier":"undefined","merchantAdjustmentDescription":"test","transactionAmount":"150.00","batchPrefix":"IF","transactionCode":"Failed 6"}}"
```

and to convert string into object

```
var object = JSON.parse(String)
```

Comment: `"{"taskStatus":"Failed","taskFields":{"originalTransactionDate":"2017-08-17","transactionPostingDate":"2017-08-17","referenceNumber":"12345","promotionIdentifier":"undefined","merchantAdjustmentDescription":"test","transactionAmount":"150.00","batchPrefix":"IF","transactionCode":""Failed"6"}}"`
Can you pls try and let me know if this working for you or not?

Comment: No, The JSON String is wrong
,"transactionCode":""Failed"6"}}"

Here Your JSON String goes wrong

Comment: Ok so because of that reason i am not able to convert into object. Thanks :)

Comment: @rahulPawar Anytime..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = '{"taskStatus":"Failed","taskFields":{"originalTransactionDate":"2017-08-17","transactionPostingDate":"2017-08-17","referenceNumber":"12345","promotionIdentifier":"undefined","merchantAdjustmentDescription":"test","transactionAmount":"150.00","batchPrefix":"IF","transactionCode":"Failed6"}}';

str = JSON.parse(str);
document.write(JSON.stringify(str));
```

```html
<h1>Your string input have double quote the end "transactionCode":<del>"</del>"Failed6"</h1>
```